# RequestMappings not working at all

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-mvc

web.xml :

```
 <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

I have appended this to web.xml

```
 <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <jsp-config>
        <jsp-property-group>
            <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
            <page-encoding>utf-8</page-encoding>
        </jsp-property-group>
    </jsp-config>
```

and now applciationContext.xml contains this

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.myCorectBasePackage"/>
```

and controller looks like this :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/Home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getHome(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("data", "myData");
        System.out.println("wtf");
        return "index";
    }
```

But the urls are resovling to 404 :

```
http://localhost:8080/myWar/Home
```

FAIL!

Server log loooks good

```
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor ws.xml from C:\Users\myProfile\.IntelliJIdea11\system\tomcat\Unnamed_myWar_2\conf\Catalina\localhost
Sep 28, 2012 4:21:18 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Sep 28, 2012 4:21:18 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Sep 28, 2012 4:21:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 3324 ms
Connected to server
```

And @Vacumn here's the auto generated deployment descriptor

```
<Context antiJARLocking="true" docBase="E:\jetbrains-workspace\myWar\target\myWar" path="/myWar" />
```

Comment: Does your container log anything from Spring, especially when the application is deployed?

Comment: @DavidGrant only the message saying everythign is ok, that looks right doesn't it. I am not missing anything ?

Comment: Can you login to the admin console of the server and check if it deployed with the proper context ? Also, add an index.html file to see that it is properly deployed.

Comment: show your context configuration

Comment: @Chris I am not sure what you mean ? oh, tomcat manager ?

Comment: @vacuum I have included the relevant mvc annotation driven, that is all that is required to get request mappings to work isn't it ?

Comment: if you are using log4j(or anything else) for logging, can you see whats being logged by spring
log4j.logger.org.springframework=DEBUG

Comment: @bluesman: if there was a binding error, it'd be logged at `ERROR`

Comment: Yes. login and make sure that context is indeed what you are trying with. Then deploy the war with a index.html. Then try `http://localhost:8080/myWar/index.html`

Comment: @NimChimpsky you also need to tell Tomcat where your war-file will be deployed(on root or myWar)

Comment: @vacuum sorry you've lost me, what part of config to you want to see ?

Comment: @Chris specifiing index.jsp in root did actually resolve. The request mappings don't work ...

Comment: file from C:\Users\myProfile\.IntelliJIdea11\system\tomcat\Unnamed_myWar_2\conf\Catalina\localhost

Comment: @NimChimpsky Do you have `@Controller` annotation for the class where `getHome()` method is defined ?

Comment: @Chris yeah just a plain old controller

Comment: @Vacumn they are created by itnellij so should work, but will update answer

Comment: And how and where is the controller bean created?

Comment: its in a class annoted @Controller, in a subpackage of my base package

Comment: @NimChimpsky So I'm assuming you have checked the spring logs and seen that your request was matched correctly by the requestmatcher?

Comment: Just getting this in log "GET /myWarHome/Home HTTP/1.1" 404 952 everythign else looks good

Comment: You're pointing the servlet to /WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml but you say the `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` is in applicationContext.xml? Is that correct? I think it has to be in spring-servlet.xml for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Define your XML configuration file as `context-param` and not as `init-param`

```
<context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I want you to add InternalResourceViewResolver entry to spring configuration:

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
           class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
           <property name="prefix">
              <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
           </property>
           <property name="suffix">
              <value>.jsp</value>
           </property>
        </bean>
```

Comment: If this not the case, please add the xml file content

Comment: Can you try to access spring-servlet.xml as I did above, instead of classpath. I faced few issues related to `classpath:` way some time back

Comment: One more thing is to add InternalResourceViewResolver. Will adding it to the answer

Comment: InternalResource won't make a difference will it ? Its not even correctly mappig the requests yet ... but yeah will try it. Thanks for the assitance btw.

Answer (score 0):

If you have annotation driven Controllers, you would probably do

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.package1, com.package2"/>
```